# Android calendar add event like activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

How to add an action bar like the one in the attached image to an activity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In simpler way you can use 2 button in linear layout by giving equal weight to them and play with visibility by using INVISIBLE,GONE,VISIBLE as per your requirement

Comment: Hi, I've found this [DoneBar](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW). Thank you.